# What would cause a Firebase function to timeout on load?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I've got several functions in my project. After leaving them for a few hours, they'll go to sleep, like usual. However, when I go to use them, they'll take about a minute or two before anything happens, and the client just gets a 500 error.

In the Firebase console, I see that the function errored with "load timeout". Sometimes, I'll have to run a function 3 or 4 times before it loads correctly and actually runs. After that, it's fine until it goes back to sleep.

I haven't be able to find anyone else who has this issue. Searches for "load timeout" don't bring up anything.

What might cause this? How can I diagnose it?

Comment: Please show the minimal code for a function that exhibits this behavior.

Comment: @DougStevenson Unfortunately I'm working with a proprietary application. I was hoping someone had some ideas or had maybe encountered the same issue. I don't have anything I can share publicly at this point, but if I can create a minimal reproducible example, I'll post that. I do appreciate your response though!

Comment: You might be making a mistake somewhere, but without code, it's hard to say.  At the very least it will be helpful to know what kind of trigger you're writing and what you're trying to do in it.

Comment: @DougStevenson I've only had this issue with HTTP request functions; the database functions take a long time time (~20 seconds) to warm up, but they've never failed to load. The HTTP functions all have a few large external dependencies that could cause an issue: `jsdom`, `ramda`, `@google-cloud/storage`, and `firebase-admin`

Comment: Check cloud function status: https://status.firebase.google.com/
In my case there was an incident today that produced this error.
https://twitter.com/leblancmeneses/status/898400647141142531

Comment: Update: I emailed Firebase support, and they eventually said it was an issue on their end. It's been a few days and I haven't had any issues. Hopefully it's been fixed.